# Can sets $A,B,C$ satisfy $(A\in B \in C) \land (A \subseteq B \subseteq C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have a union of criteria: $$(A\in B \in C) \land (A \subseteq B \subseteq C)$$
Can such sets exist? 
I spent some time thinking about this and I came up with this example: 
$$A = \{ a\}$$ $$B = \{ \{ a\}, a  \}$$ $$C = \{ \{  \{a \}, a\}, \{a\}, a \}$$ 
Can this actually work?

Comment: Why are you doubting if it works?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks right to me!

---

It's worth noting that the key to the problem, which you picked up on at least intuitively but is worth saying out loud, is: *sets of mixed rank*. Intuitively, a set like "$\{a, \{a\}\}$" might feel weird since the elements "$a$" and "$\{a\}$" seem like different types of things, and outside of set theory we usually deal with sets of objects of the same type (e.g. sets of real numbers, sets of continuous functions, sets of groups, ...).

But the idea that sets of mixed rank are totally okay is a key intuition in set theory. Indeed, such sets are extremely useful - e.g. [ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) are such sets. This problem is (I think) trying to make you comfortable with such objects.

---

On the "ordinals" note above, note that $a$ isn't really playing any role in your solution: we could also have $$A=\{\}, B=\{\{\}\}, C=\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\},$$ and these sets are exactly the first three ordinals (and this pattern continues: one of the key points about ordinals is that $\alpha\in\beta$ implies $\alpha\subseteq\beta$). Getting used to building stuff from the emptyset alone is another important part of learning set theory.

Comment: I know (and appreciate) that nested empty sets are an elegant method to define or derive the natural numbers. But my intuition seems to complain that a set is a purely mental construct which does not take on an existence of its own. (I know that that is a funny thing to say in the context of mathematics ;-).) A set of things is simply a way of saying "I'm talking about these things". The empty set is another way of saying "nothing". A set containing the empty set still contains exactly that: Nothing, and hence is the empty set, too ...

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Except the empty set *isn't* nothing any more than a bag containing nothing is nothing. One way to think about "pure sets" is to view them as rigid well-founded trees; then the empty set corresponds to the one-point tree. Another way to motivate ZFC-style set theory is to first think about building a "structure-of-sets" on a given mathematical structure - that is, a model of ZFC *with atoms*. This gives you a lot of power to analyze the structure in question. We can ask what sort of expressive power is common to all such constructions; this amounts to throwing away the atoms.

Comment: @Peter: If the empty set is "nothing"; surely $0$ is nothing. But if $0$ is nothing, and $1$ is the "successor of nothing", well, then there is nothing to succeed, so $1$ is nothing; but then $2$ as the successor of $1$ is also the successor of nothing, so $2$ is nothing by the same argument. And this can continue by induction to prove that everything is nothing. The same logic applies to set. Nothing *is not something*, but everything in the universe [of mathematics] is *something*. Therefore everything is not nothing, and the empty set is something, and so not nothing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was not talking about the application of nested empty sets to define "successions", i.e. ordinals. I was expressing my intuitive discomfort with viewing them in a way which makes that possible. This view of empty sets contradicts my intuitive semantics of sets. Say: *I have nothing and you have nothing (each of our sets of possessions is empty). I give you the set of all my possessions. Suddenly your set of possessions is not empty anymore: It contains an empty set of possessions. That is different from no possessions at all.* A set is regarded a *thing*, which is weird.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, I understand that. Which is the source of my comment. Your intuition should not be that $0$ or $\varnothing$ are "nothing". They are *something*. If you gave me nothing, then the *collection* of what you gave me is the empty set. You haven't given me the empty set itself. Your confusion arises from an incorrect interpretation of what it means to be a set. Just like you haven't given me "zero", but rather "the number of things you have given me" is zero. The map is not the territory, the menu is not the food.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I have an empty bag, you have an empty bag. I put my empty bag in your empty bag. Now your bag isn't empty anymore. Sets are objects in the same way that bags can be put into other bags. (This isn't a perfect analogy obviously - bags are more like multisets - but it addresses the intuitive issue you're describing.)

Answer (score 15):

Perfect, you actually recovered the structure of the first nonzero ordinals: $1,2,3$. Starting with the set $a$ you applied the successor function $S(x):=x\cup\{x\}$ which is the first method for building bigger ordinals. Ordinals are $\in$-transitive. Id est $x\in y$ and $y\in z$ implies $x\in z$ which could seem strange at first glance, beating our level-idea of sets.

Comment: Actually I write from Italy, so I studied a bit of Latin :D (even if it looks more similar to English than to Italian)